# How to override the metaclass constructor in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want a piece of code to run before any other static methods run, is it possible to do something in the spirit of the following?

```
class MyClass
  def self.initialize
    @stuff = 1
  end
  def self.print_stuff
    puts @stuff
  end
end
```

My Ruby version of interest is 2.3.

Comment: Replace the method `MyClass::initialize` with simply `@stuff = 1`. The class instance variable `@stuff` is assigned the value `1` when the class definition is parsed. I don't think the metaprogramming tag is appropriate here.

Comment: It's hard to figure out what you're asking if you invent your own terminology without defining it. There is no such thing as a *static method* in Ruby, nor does Ruby have constructors.

Answer (score 1):

Every chunk of code in Ruby is an expression. Even a class definition is a series of expressions: method definitions are expressions that have the side-effect of adding the method to the class.

This is how meta-programming methods work. `attr_reader` is a private method call where the implicit `self` is the class. So, long story short, you aren't restricted inside a class body, you can put whatever code you want to run in the context of the class:

```
class MyClass
  @stuff = 1

  def self.print_stuff
    puts @stuff
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as an explicit metaclass initializer. The class itself is "initialized" as it's defined, so it's perfectly valid to do this:

```
class MyClass
  # Code here will be executed as the class itself is defined.
  @stuff = 1

  def self.print_stuff
    puts @stuff
  end
end

MyClass.print_stuff
```

Remember that `def` itself is a form of method call and defining a class in Ruby involves sending a bunch of messages (method calls) around to the proper context objects, such as the class itself as it's being defined.